# Can I solve a metric equation using Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following metric which tells how the length of a infinitesimally small section of space is determined:
$$ds^2=-(c+A\space t)^2dt^2+dr^2\tag 1$$
For a null geodesic, $ds^2$ will be zero, so I know that I can reorder the equation as:
$$0=-(c+A\space t)^2dt^2+dr^2$$
$$0=-(c+A\space t)^2+\frac{dr^2}{dt^2}$$
I can then solve this equation using DSolve and solve for $r[t]$:

```
DSolve[0 == -(c + A*t)^2 + D[r[t], t]^2, r[t], t]
```

My question is: this involves me performing some analysis of the equation in order to set it up for DSolve.  Is there a way to solve for $r[t]$ using equation (1) and some sort of differential notation (that doesn't require me to analyze the equation first)?

Comment: $(1)$ is not an equation, but a metric definition. Whenever attempting to solve a differential equation, giving up of "analyzing equations first"  is the worst strategy. Anyone who wants to solve equations before trying to understand their meaning,  makes himself a parasite.

Answer (score 2):

You did not give many examples to use. But for the example you give, see if this works for you. This assumes you already set $ds=0$.  You can't mix and match in this. So `eq = -(c + A t)^2 dt^2 + dr^2 + dr + dt` will not work. All `dr` and `dt` has to be same power and only one pair of them.

```
ClearAll[c, A, t, dr, dt];
eq = -(c + A t)^2 dt^2 + dr^2 ;
eq = fix[eq, dr, dt, r, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[eq == 0, r[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = -(c + A t)^2 dt^3 + dr^3 ;
eq = fix[eq, dr, dt, r, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[eq == 0, r[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = -(c + A t)^2 dt + dr;
eq = fix[eq, dr, dt, r, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DSolve[eq == 0, r[t], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
fix[eq0_, dr_, dt_, r_, t_] := Module[{dummy, eq = eq0, exponent},
   exponent = Exponent[eq, dr, List];

   If[ exponent[[1]] == 0 && Length[exponent] > 2 || 
      exponent[[1]] != 0 && Length[exponent] > 1 || exponent == {0},
      Print["Not supported or missing dr"]
    ,
      exponent = Exponent[eq, dr];
      eq = Expand[eq/dt^exponent ];
      eq = (eq /. {dr -> dummy dt}) /. dummy dt -> dr /. dummy -> r'[t]
    ];

   eq
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know I can write code to do it.  That's probably more work than analyzing the expression.  I was looking for a dimension of the language that would handle the differentials as language elements.